# Get a list of all files in a git repository with changes, ignoring white-space changes

Tags: git

I try to get a list of all files that have changes, but ignoring white-space changes.

It works fine with

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space --ignore-cr-at-eol
```

which just relevant changes, but when I add `--name-only`, I still get the files, that have only white-space changes.

How do I get only the names of files with relevant changes?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to have Git actually generate the diffs. This is almost certainly a bug, and a future Git will probably have it fixed (possibly as early as Git 2.30, someone is working on a related issue now).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal diff and check each file, if a diff, that ignores the whitespace will produce an output:

```
IGNORE="--ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space --ignore-cr-at-eol"
for f in $(git diff --name-only ); do
  if [ "$(git diff $IGNORE "$f")" != "" ]; then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done
```